# howto disable format-dection on dates?

Tags: iphone, mobile-website

How do I disable format-detection on **dates** on iphone mobile webapp,
I've tried

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

which doesn't work - (after all, it's a date, not a phonenumber...)

Comment: workable and ugly:     $d = str_replace('-','<span style="font-size:0px;">x</span>-',$d);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

workable and ugly: $d = str_replace('-','x-',$d)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can play with UIWebview's dataDetectorType to achieve what you want.